# php error Warning: Undefined array key "key"

Tags: php

I needed to create a php logic so that it would compare the entered text in the field with the text previously added to the table. And the logic seems to be correctly spelled out. But why does the

```
Warning error: Undefined array key "key"
```

and

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 pop up? You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key=NULL' at line 1 in /var/www/********/data/www/*********************/check.php:13 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/********/data/www/*********************/check.php(13): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/********/data/www/*********************/check.php on line 13
```

And I don't understand why. I tried many ways, including hiding this error, but it's useless. Help solve this issue.

I have a problem in an undefined array. But the logic seems to be spelled out correctly, but I don't understand what's wrong here.

And also I don't understand the reason for the fatal error.

```
$sql->execute(array('key' => $key));  <----ERROR
```

here's the logic:

```
   $key = $_POST["key"];
   $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM key_store key=:key");
   $sql->execute(array('key' => $key)); <----ERROR
   $array=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   
   if($array["id"]>0){

$_SESSION['key']=$array["id"];
header('Location: center.php?id='.$array["id"]);
}else{
    header('Location: sorry.php');
}
```

I have tried many ways, including hiding the error. But I didn't get the desired result

Comment: Since $_POST doesn't contain a "key" property, that must be because you didn't submit one to the php script. So check the code or html markup which invokes this script.

Comment: The sql error is because you forgot the `WHERE`. It should be `SELECT id FROM key_store WHERE key=:key"`. Always check your work carefully

Comment: `key` also is a reserved term. Consider renaming or use backticks, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-K.

Comment: Regarding your update: I've already told you what to check to investigate the undefined array key. The duplicate link's answer also mentions this. Was there something you didn't understand from my earlier comments? If so please specify it and we can try to clarify further